# Setting security-settings for MQTT in Artemis

Tags: mqtt, activemq-artemis

I am trying to control which topics Artemis users can use with MQTT. I have Artemis working and can send/listen to MQTT topics using: `match="#"` but if I try to restrict the the match for some topics to: `match="userA.#"` (similar to most examples in the documentation) I cannot send and do not receive any messages.

I went into the admin console and saw that my retained topic `userA/test` got the addresses `$sys.mqtt.retain.userA.test` so I tried prefixing the match but that did not work either.

So to my question: can you restrict MQTT topic access using `security-settings`, and if so how do you do it?

Is there a better way of doing it, for example using/writing a SimpleMQTTInterceptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem here is the syntax of the `match` versus the topic name. Your match is `userA.#` but your topic is `userA/test`. Notice that `.` is not equal to `/`. Try changing your configuration to:

```xml
<wildcard-addresses>
   <delimiter>/</delimiter>
</wildcard-addresses>
```

And then change your match to be `userA/#`.

Wildcard syntax configuration is discussed in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/wildcard-syntax.html).

Comment: I thought the broker would be smart enough to translate that for each protocol, otherwise you cannot really use multiple protocols at the same time on a broker? Anyway, I tried it and still I cannot get send or listen to matched sub topics. You don't happen to have a working example for mqtt?

Comment: Of all the protocols which the broker supports MQTT is the only one with a specific syntax like this. You can certainly use multiple protocols simultaneously, they'll just need to use the same syntax for their destinations. I don't have any MQTT examples with security at the moment.

Comment: I set up a test in the Artemis test-suite and everything looks like it's work as expected. You could perhaps fork and modify the [MQTT publish-subscribe example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/protocols/mqtt/publish-subscribe) shipped with Artemis to demonstrate what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks this helped! The real issue why I did not get it to work was this documentation [link](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.2.0/security.html) which states the roles format as user=roles not role=users as it should be. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you talking about the documentation for the `PropertiesLoginModule`? If so, the docs clearly states, "The `artemis-roles.properties` file consists of a list of properties of the form, `Role=UserList`, where `UserList` is a comma-separated list of users." Also, the documentation you linked is for ActiveMQ Artemis 1.2.0 which is quite old now. The latest release is 2.11.0. Those docs are [here](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/).